# The Mt.Fuji vs Mt.Fuji. When do I use "the"?

Tags: articles

Why do we say **The** Amazon river and not **The** Mt.Fuji?

For example,
I climbed Mt.Fuji.

I swam in **the** Amazon river.

I hiked along **the** Silk road.

Comment: http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/using_english_articles10.html

Comment: You *would* use it, if you were to say, perhaps: We climbed *the great Mt. Fuji*.

Comment: And, I don't think *the* is needed before 'Silk road', unless it's a part of the name: 'The Silk Road'.

Comment: “No article is necessary before the following specific nouns: Singular names of countries or territories, cities, towns, states, streets, lakes, bays, mountains, continents, islands, languages, sports, academic subjects.”

Comment: There are specific exceptions, like _The Hague_, but this is generally right. Also there are constructions like modified nouns (_the buzzing New York City, the famous Fifth Avenue_) which may need articles; this applies only to simple nouns and names.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, a noun usually include an article. I personally think it is a remnant of the English language's relationship with the Romance language.

e.g the Netherlands, the Philippines, the Silk Road.

There  are, however, no rules governing it.